# $(\liminf_{n}A_{n})\cap (\limsup_{n}B_{n}) \subset \limsup_{n}(A_{n}\cap B_{n})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

$(A_{n})_{n}$ and $(B_{n})_{n}$ sequences of subsets of $Ω$. Show that:

$$(\liminf A_{n})\cap (\limsup B_{n}) \subset (\limsup A_{n})\cap (\limsup B_{n})$$ and $$(\liminf A_{n})\cap (\limsup B_{n}) \subset \limsup (A_{n}\cap B_{n})$$

I am a bit confused with the set theory but I tried to prove them. I know that $\liminf A_{n} \subset \limsup A_{n}$ so the first part looks easy. For the second part I could use the first one and then I could show that $(\limsup A_{n})\cap (\limsup B_{n}) \subset \limsup (A_{n} \cap B_{n})$ but how can I know if this is always true?

Comment: Is this supposed to be limes inferior etc.?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Limit superior and limit inferior, yes

Comment: Use `$\inf A_n$` for $\inf A_n$ and `$\sup A_n$` for $\sup A_n$.

Comment: Ok, I formatted `\lim inf` as `\liminf`, but the statements still look odd.

Answer (score 1):

$x\in\lim\inf A_n$ means that $x$ belongs to almost all (i.e. all but finitely many) of the sets $A_n$.

$x\in\lim\sup B_n$ means that $x$ belongs to infinitely many of the sets $B_n$.

If $x$ belongs to both, it then means that $x$ also belongs to infinitely many of the sets $A_n\cap B_n$ (precisely the *infinitely* many sets where $x\in B_n$, minus *finitely* many of those where $x\not\in A_n$).

This proves that $x\in\lim\sup (A_n\cap B_n)$.

Comment: I understood it! One more question: If we follow my way, is it always true that $(\limsup A_{n})\cap (\limsup B_{n}) \subset \limsup (A_{n} \cap B_{n})$ ?

Comment: @CodingGuy It looks to me that your inclusion there should be reversed... which then makes it less than useful for your purpose :( If $x$ is in infinitely many of the sets $A_n\cap B_n$, then it is trivially in infinitely many of $A_n$'s and $B_n$'s, but the opposite may not be true. (Let $x$ be in $A_n$ for $n$ odd, and in $B_n$ for $n$ even, for example.)